# MySQL: select query, 5 minute increment

Tags: mysql, sql, pchart

I have a weather database which gets datasets about every 70 seconds (depends on when the weather-station delivers the data).
I want to graph it using Pchart but i have too many samples so the X axis is screwed up.
So i want the data for about every 5 minutes. (or every 30 minutes)
The query i currently have is this:

```
SELECT time, temp_out FROM wmr200 WHERE date(time) = curdate()
```

This gets the samples for the last 24 hours but there are too many.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following will get you a sample consisting of any data with a timestamp at :00, :05, :10 ...

```
SELECT time, temp_out FROM wmr200 WHERE date(time) = curdate()
    AND mod(minute(time),5) = 0
```

I'm using the modulo function to check if the minute part of the time is (0 or) divisible by 5.

---

If you need only one result for each time segment, we've got to get quite a bit more complex.

```
SELECT concat(date(time),' ',hour(time),':',round(minute(time)/5,0)*5), 
       min(temp_out), avg(temp_out), max(temp_out) 
FROM wmr200 
GROUP BY date(time), hour(time), round(minute(time)/5,0)*5
```

I don't have access to a MySQL instance to test it out right now, but here's the idea. It groups by every five minutes, by grouping by date, hour, and `round(minute(time)/5,0)*5` - which rounds minute to the nearest 5.

It selects the value of time that it should be grouped around, and the min, avg, and max temp_out, as I wasn't sure which of these would best apply to your situation.

If, however, your DB doesn't have data for a five minute stretch (or 30 minute stretch, if that's what you're using), it still may not have data for a sample point.

Comment: I changed it to this: 
SELECT time, temp_out FROM wmr200 WHERE date(time) = curdate()
    AND mod(minute(time),30) = 0

But some samples seem to miss, or i get duplicates.
Since the data is not stored in a steady pase..

Comment: Example output:  
`2012-05-01 00:00:18 4.4  
2012-05-01 00:30:51 4.4  
2012-05-01 01:00:01 4.3  
2012-05-01 01:00:50 4.3`

Comment: @HyperDevil I edited in a possible solution. I can't test it atm, so let me know how it works.

Comment: would it be possible to only see the the hour:minute?
Also the minute function seems to print 60, but the mysql documentation only says the range of the minute command is 0 to 59...?

Comment: Certainly. The `concat(...)` function concatenates all of those strings together. If you don't want the date, remove the `date(time)` and `' '` strings. As to the 60, the `round(minute(time)/5,0)*5` function groups by closest 5, so it rounds up to 60, that's my fault. I can't seem to come up with a quick fix at the moment, I'll return and try to help with that when I have time.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else happens upon this page, here's a solution that's comparable to Sam's. It makes use of Unix timestamps and integer division to "bin" and average values over any arbitrary time period.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) div (5*60))*(5*60)+(5*60)) as timeIntervals,
round(avg(temp_out),3) as temp_out
FROM wmr200 
GROUP BY 1
```